# visual studio web project edit

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

This feels ridiculous, but here goes:

I have a web application project (started by colleague, down from tfs) that I trying to open in Visual Studio 2010. When I open my project I get the following error message:

> The Web Site 'http://localhost:60173' is configured to use IIS Express as the web server. To open this Web Site, you must download and install IIS Express. Would you like to download it now using Web Platform Installer?

I dont' want to run anything. All I want to do is look at code and edit it. Why can't I?

All questions/answers on the web on this error message is from people who actually have IIS Express installed, and can't make it work. This is not my issue. I just want to edit code, so WT*

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `.csproj` or `vbproj` file. Find and replace these entries

```
<UseIIS>true</UseIIS> by <UseIIS>false</UseIIS>
<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress> by <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
```

Comment: Not possible to try that because searching for UseIIS over the whole solution yields no results.

Comment: @cprebenbang, Go to Project Foler find .csproj file and edit with notepad

Comment: There is no "UseIIS" in any .csproj file in the folder. So maybe the solution is set up wrong?

Comment: @cprebenbang, search for => UseIISExpress instead